# Dope sheet: display keyframes even if element is hidden

Tags: animation, visibility

I animate a lot the visibility property:

[image]

Unfortunately, when an element is not visible anymore, the keyframes do not appear anymore in the dope sheet even with the `show hidden` button (tested on blender 3.1.0), unless I also uncheck the `Only show selected`, but then it's a mess:

[image]

Any idea how I could both animate the visibility and keep the keyframes visible?

Actually, I have the feeling that the problem is that when an element is not visible, it is not displayable in the dope sheet... so even if I just move my keyframes and while moving the keyframes the current frame turns out to contain the invisible object, then everything stops being visible in the dope sheet, and I can't select it anymore... I guess this is a bug, but I don't know if you know workarounds. Also, the "search" does not work either when I display all elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you guessed it, you need to do this:

[image: display restrictions]

It has been requested for quite a while that Blender doesn't change selection when hiding/unhiding objects, and more importantly don't make it impossible to select a hidden object. Hopefully this will be done one day. But in the meantime, we have to deal with it as is.

A way around, though not practical when you have many objects, is to drive an objects visibility by another object. That way, you always have the keys available. But it's time-consuming to set up and not scalable.

[image: demo Drivers]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Too bad search does not work when all items are visible. And thanks for the workaround with drivers, it may turn out to be practical sometimes... For instance by combining it with custom properties. And I didn't know it was possible to copy/paste drivers, that's cool !

Comment: Yeah that was introduced somewhere between 2.80 and 2.83 i think, such a time saver! And yes, you can totally use custom properties or anything you want. Just do it on a keyable value on an object that remains visible just so that it remains on the dopesheet.